# mapping function to key in vim that yanks line out of one buffer, adds something to the line and puts it into a different buffer

Tags: vim

In a .c file, I want to press F2 on a function definition, yank that definition into a register put it into the .h file and add a semicolon to the line.

I've got the yanking part down.

```
:nmap  <F2> "aY
```

The rest is a problem to me.

```
:nmap  <F2> "aY :let@a.=";"<CR>
```

puts the semicolon on a newline

and I don't even know how I would address the buffer as a target.
I know that `:b<number>` changes to one, but I don't know how to address a specific one.

Update:

```
nmap <F2> "aY :b12<CR>"ap A;<ESC>:b11<CR>
```

works.

with :b12 being the header and :b11 being the source, but as expected, it only works by switching buffers in the current window.
Isn't there a way to do this directly?

Answer (score 1):

For buffer switching part you could use a.vim plugin:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31

Alternatively use function like:

```
fun! ToggleCSourceHeader()
  if (expand ("%:e") == "c")
    find %:t:r.h
  else
    find %:t:r.c
  endif
endfun
```